# Type Error when multiplying slope by a list of X

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, linear-regression

**Below is the problem I am running into:**

*Linear Regression - Given 16 pairs of prices (as dependent variable) and
corresponding demands (as independent variable), use the linear regression tool to estimate the best fitting
linear line.*

```
Price Demand
127 3420
134 3400
136 3250
139 3410
140 3190
141 3250
148 2860
149 2830 
151 3160
154 2820
155 2780
157 2900
159 2810
167 2580
168 2520
171 2430
```

**Here is my code:**

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
from scipy.stats import *


x = [3420, 3400, 3250, 3410, 3190, 3250, 2860, 2830, 3160, 2820, 2780, 2900, 2810, 2580, 2520, 2430]
    np.asarray(x,dtype= np.float64)

y = [127, 134, 136 ,139, 140, 141, 148, 149, 151, 154, 155, 157, 159, 167, 168, 171]
np.asarray(y, dtype= np.float64)

slope,intercept,r_value,p_value,slope_std_error = stats.linregress(x,y)

y_modeled = x*slope+intercept

plot(x,y,'ob',markersize=2)
plot(x,y_modeled,'-r',linewidth=1)
show()
```

**Here is the error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-0a0274c24b19>", line 13, in <module>
    y_modeled = x*slope+intercept

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not convert the Python lists to numpy arrays here:

```
x = [3420, 3400, 3250, 3410, 3190, 3250, 2860, 2830, 3160, 2820, 2780, 2900, 2810, 2580, 2520, 2430]
np.asarray(x,dtype= np.float64)
```

`np.asarray` returns a numpy array, but does not modify the original. You can do this instead:

```
x = [3420, 3400, 3250, 3410, 3190, 3250, 2860, 2830, 3160, 2820, 2780, 2900, 2810, 2580, 2520, 2430]
x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float64)
```

There is a big difference in how numpy array multiplication works compared to how Python list multiplication works. See here:

```
>>> 3 * np.array([1, 2, 3])
array([3, 6, 9])

>>> 3 * [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

In your case, you tried to do the latter (list multiplication), but you multiplied with a float, which cannot work and that is what the error said.

Comment: THANK YOU! This fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

First, [i*slope+intercept for i in x] is list comprehension, where you will be multiplying each number in the list "x" with the slope and adding to it the interception.
Then you will pass the new values of list "x" to the np.asarray() to convert the list into a numpy array.

```
Y_modeled=np.asarray([i*slope+intercept for i in x], dtype=np.float64)
```

Comment: Even though this may answer the question, there is no explanation of your code. Please update your answer to provide an explanation of what you are doing. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks.@Miroslav Glamuzina